# How can I stop refreshing the page in the else condition

Tags: asp.net, refresh

My code:

```
protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (txtReportFavorite.Text != string.Empty)
     {
         //..
     }
     else
     {
         Response.Write("<script>alert('Enter Favorite name.')</script>");
         // I need to prevent page refresh here.
     }
 }
```

How can I stop refreshing the page in the else condition. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about page refresh or postback?

Comment: It's too late to prevent page reload at this stage of the pipeline: If your server code is called, the page is already refreshing (postback in progress). You can however display the same page. If you really want to prevent page refresh, use js clientside.

Comment: You mean do not postback the page after a button Click?

Comment: why would it refresh ? you dont have any code for refresh! if you dont want to refresh then you have to handle it at the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The new page has already been requested when that code runs. If you don't do a postback, that code will never run.

If you want to do the validation without doing the postback, you should do it using client code instead.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you got to the server side means that your page has done a full cycle to the server and refreshed itself.

Unless you are calling this code with an Ajax call.

You can also achieve this by placing an AjaxUpdatePanel around your button that will simulate an Ajax call when your clients will submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of functionality you are showing can be easily achieved by using a Validator so the page won't post back.

As once it reaches the server, its really not possible to stop the refresh. Well, at least as far as I know.
-Milind

Answer (score 0):

in your code behind on page load put this

```
btnOk.Attributes.Add("onclick","return validate();");
```

in your aspx file have this script

```
function validate()
{
    if(document.getElementById("txtReportFavorite").value == "";
      {             
                alert("Enter Favorite name");
                return false;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page is already go to the server side and it is in already postback is progressing.

you have to use client side code for preventing postback.

Answer (score 0):

why not to use RequiredFieldValidator if only empty textbox need to validate?
you can do it on client side.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtReportFavorite" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="txtReportFavorite" controltovalidate="txtName" errormessage="Enter Favorite name!" />
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" text="Ok" onclick="btn_Click" />

protected void btnSubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid) //for secure validation 
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RegisterScriptBlock`.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType),"","$(document).ready(function(){alert('Enter Favorite name.')});",true);
```

If you want to perform from server-side do it like above.. Otherwise many answers already posted.